# how can I use media queries when I want to override the app bar height in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

```
class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double appBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .3;

    return AppBar(
      brightness: Brightness.light,

      automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // hides leading widget

      title: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
        child: TyperAnimatedTextKit(
            speed: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            isRepeatingAnimation: false,
            text: [
              "SANDRA",
            ],
            textStyle: GoogleFonts.permanentMarker(
                fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.black),
            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart // or Alignment.topLeft

            ),
      ),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(88);
}
```

this is my code, I want to use media queries to make the app responsive in different screens, how can I use media queries in this case instead of **88** at the end of the my code? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing `PreferredSizeWidget`, you could use `PreferredSize`:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(MediaQuery.of(context)...),
      child: AppBar(...),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I wanted to put the app bar in a separate file, that's why I implemented the preferred size widget.
is it possible to find a solution and also put the app bar in a separate file?

Comment: No, but you could make a custom Scaffold instead.